# PHP curl dosen't copy existing file to external server

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to copy an existing file from my server to an external server using `curl`

The `Form class` has two methods.
The `insert_data` method creates the file and insert it to an existing folder and table in the local server.

The second method try to copy the file to a remote server to an existing folder

The remote `CURLOPT_URL` points to the `upload.php` file in the remote server.

I have to problems,

1. for some reason I can't activate the  `copy_file_to_ext_server()` method from inside the `insert_data()` method.
2. I cant transfer the file to the remote server.

This is the class on the local server:

```
<?php
/**
 * Form class inserts form data to dataabse
 */
class Form
{

    function __construct()
    {

        $this->dbh = dbconnect::getDbh();
        if (!$this->dbh) {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }
    }

    public function insert_data($lname, $fname, $idNo, $img, $upload_dir)
    {

        $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM vitur_sodiut WHERE idno=?');
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $idNo);
        $stmt->execute();
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if (!$row) {
            $img       = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
            $img       = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
            $data      = base64_decode($img);
            $file_name = $idNo . ".png";
            $file      = $upload_dir . "" . $idNo . ".png"; //file destination
            $success   = file_put_contents($file, $data);



            $query = $this->dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO vitur_sodiut (lname, fname, file, idno) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)");
            $query->bindparam(1, $lname);
            $query->bindparam(2, $fname);
            $query->bindparam(3, $file);
            $query->bindparam(4, $idNo);

            self::copy_file_to_ext_server($file, $file_name);


            try {
                $query->execute();
                if (!$query) { 
                    echo "Failure conncting db!";
                }
            }
            catch (PDOException $e) {
                die($e->getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            echo 'value already exists in the table';
        }
    }


    public function copy_file_to_ext_server($file, $file_name)
    {
     echo $file;

        $ch    = curl_init();
        $cfile = new CURLFile($file, 'image/png', $file_name);
        print_r($cfile);
        $filedata = array(
            "myimage" => $cfile
        );

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://myserver.co/folder/upload.php");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $cfile);

        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($response == true) {
            echo "file posted";
        } else {
            echo "Error" . curl_error($ch);
        }
    }
}
?>
```

This is the `http://myserver.co/folder/upload.php` content:

```
<?php

if(isset($file)){
    $path = "uploads/". $file_name;
    move_uploaded_file($file, $path);
}

?>
```

I tried using also this method instead of `copy_file_to_ext_server` but with no success.

```
/* Remote File Name and Path */
$local_file = $file;

/* FTP Account (Remote Server) */
$ftp_host = 'http://myserver'; /* host */
$ftp_user_name = 'username'; /* username */
$ftp_user_pass = 'password'; /* password */


/* File and path to send to remote FTP server */
$remote_file = '/public_html/a11y/' . $file_name;

/* Connect using basic FTP */
$connect_it = ftp_connect( $ftp_host );


/* Login to FTP */
$login_result = ftp_login( $connect_it, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass );

/* Send $local_file to FTP */
if ( ftp_put( $connect_it, $remote_file, $local_file, FTP_BINARY ) ) {
   echo "WOOT! Successfully transfer $local_file\n";
}
else {
   echo "Doh! There was a problem\n";
}

/* Close the connection */
ftp_close( $connect_it );
```

I always receive `Doh! There was a problem` Error thogh I put the ftp conection server details.

Comment: Why are u trying to use `curl` as a intermediary if you are going to upload the file over `FTP` later on?

Comment: I dont want to upload it via ftp, Just transfer an existing file from server to server.

Comment: the ftp code at the bottom is an alternative way to upload the file to the external server but it dosen't work either.

Comment: `if(isset($file)){` How should your script know, what is `$file` or `$file_name`?

Comment: ok ok you are right, it shoul d be '$_POST['file']'?

Comment: No if everything went well the data should be inside `$_FILES`

Comment: Maybe i'm really wrong here, but shouldn't this-> $ftp_host = 'http ://myserver'; be something like $ftp_host = 'ftp ://myserver'; ?

Comment: @DarkBee how do I place an existing file data in to `$_FILES` var?

Comment: You don't. That is what `CurlFile` does for you. Try `var_dump($_FILES)` on the receiving script

Comment: @Aurora, tried the ftp://myserver approach, it disent connect either...

Comment: @DarkBee  the file is created in this code :`            $img       = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
            $img       = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
            $data      = base64_decode($img);
            $file_name = $idNo . ".png";
            $file      = $upload_dir . "" . $idNo . ".png"; //file destination
            $success   = file_put_contents($file, $data); `   there in no traditional file upload in this procedure.  there is no file input field or multipart/encript  envolve.

Comment: @Aurora by the way,  "host
The FTP server address. This parameter shouldn't have any trailing slashes and shouldn't be prefixed with ftp://."  taken from http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-connect.php :)

Comment: @DavSev i know (thanks), i was giving a quick example but this comment editor can be a pain in the bum to insert the code properly. I also wantd to suggest (not sure if i'm right, just trying to help out), does the ftp user have access to the server over SSH or not? Might this be the poblem why it's not connecting?

Comment: the server i try to connect I can connect to via putty on ssh. I place in the code the has exect same details i usualy connect the server via filezilla or putty. I dont understand what is wrong... any way I gave up the `CURL ` way. now I try with the `ftp_connect` way

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple.

```
    $post = array($file,'image/png',$file_name);
    $ch    = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://myserver.co/folder/upload.php");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post );
```